# No results when using a custom ArrayAdapter and Filter

Tags: android, filtering, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom `ArrayAdapter` like in this code:

```
public class UtenteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Utente> implements Filterable {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Utente> utenti;
private ArrayList<Utente> utentiFiltrati;
private FiltroPersonalizzato filtro;

public UtenteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Utente> utenti) {
    super(context, R.layout.riga_utente, utenti);
    this.context=context;
    this.utenti=utenti;
    utentiFiltrati = new ArrayList<Utente>();
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //omitted..
    return riga;
}
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged(){
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filtro == null) {
        filtro = new FiltroPersonalizzato();
    }
    return filtro;
}
private class FiltroPersonalizzato extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
        FilterResults risultato = new FilterResults();
        ArrayList<Utente> i = new ArrayList<Utente>();
          if (prefix!= null && prefix.toString().length() > 0) {
              // use the initial values !!! 
              for (int index = 0; index < utenti.size(); index++) {
                  Utente si = utenti.get(index);
                  final int length = prefix.length();
                  // if you compare the Strings like you did it will never work as you compare the full item string(you'll have a match only when you write the EXACT word)
                  // keep in mind that you take in consideration capital letters!
                  if(si.getNome().toLowerCase().substring(0, length).compareTo(prefix.toString().toLowerCase()) == 0){
                    i.add(si);  
                  }
              }
              risultato.values = i;
              risultato.count = i.size();                   
          }
          else{
              // revert to the old values 
              synchronized (utentiFiltrati){
                  risultato.values = utenti;
                  risultato.count = utenti.size();
              }
          }
          return risultato;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        utentiFiltrati = (ArrayList<Utente>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

I have a `SearchView` and I want to filter the rows by name but I have no results after filtering. I am sure that I have results(from debugging) but if I call filter from my `ListFragment` I can't see my result:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query); 
            return true;
        }
```

I update my `ArrayAdapter` from the `ListFragment` like this:

```
private void setListaUtenti(){

    if(getListAdapter()==null){
        // creo l'adapter
        adapter=new UtenteAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                utenti);
        setListAdapter(adapter);  

    } else{
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
    }                       
}
```

Why don't I see the results of the filtering operation?

Comment: You don't see the filtered values(or any change at all) when you enter some filtered text?

Comment: i can go into onQueryTextSubmit but no element filtered..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have a searchview and i want filter row by name but i have no
>   result.

It's normal that you don't get a result as in the `publishResults()` callback of the `Filter` you assign the results to the `utentiFiltrati` list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will do nothing as your adapter is based on the `utenti` list, the one you pass to the super class constructor. Make the following changes:

```
public UtenteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Utente> utentiValues) {
    super(context, R.layout.riga_utente, utentiValues);
    this.context=context;
    this.utentiFiltrati = utentiValues;
    utenti = new ArrayList<Utente>(utentiValues);
}

// ...
FilterResults risultato = new FilterResults();
ArrayList<Utente> i;
if (prefix == null || prefix.toString().length() == 0) {
     // the contract of a Filter says that you must return all values if the
     // challenge string is null or 0 length
     i = new ArrayList<Utente>(utenti);
} else {
     i = new ArrayList<Utente>();
     // use the list that contains the full set of data
     for (int index = 0; index < utenti.size(); index++) {
           Utente si = utenti.get(index);
           final int length = prefix.length();
           if(si.getNome().toLowerCase().substring(0, length).compareTo(prefix.toString().toLowerCase()) == 0){
                i.add(si);  
           }
     }
  //...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
        FilterResults results) {
    utentiFiltrati = (ArrayList<Utente>)results.values;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: no change i tried:     adapter.getFilter().filter(query); setListaUtenti(); but i have no result yet..

Comment: @fabio How about if you do `clear(); utentiFiltrati = (ArrayList<Utente>)results.values; for (Utente item : utentiFiltrati) { add(item);}` in the `publishResults()` method?

Comment: yes now i have a result! (but it is wrong..) how i can come back before search?

Comment: @fabio What exactly does *but it is wrong* mean? *Come back before search* - Are you trying to show the unfiltered list(in which case you could just filter the list again with a `null` string)?

Comment: search is right but user that i display is wrong (i filter by "an" and i have "ago..". now i only call adapter.getFilter().filter(query);

Comment: @fabio That is related to your code and the `Utente` class(Did you override the `toString` method to return what you want to show?).

Comment: i resolved my problem (on getview i must use array filtered) thanks Luksprog!